# How to write a conditional if for user privilege in symfony 1.4 using sfGuard plugin

Tags: symfony1, if-statement, symfony-1.4

I am trying to write a condition that will check for a specific parameter and the user credentials. If the user does not have one of two credentials and passes the correct parameter, they will get forwarded to a secure login screen.

This is what I did have that worked:

```
if ($request->getParameter('profile_type') == 'foo' && !$this->getUser()->isAdmin())  {
      return $this->redirect('sfGuardAuth/secure');
    }
```

But I have added a new user group so I need something like this:

```
if ($request->getParameter('profile_type') == 'foo' && (!$this->getUser()->isAdmin() || !$this->getUser()->isFaculty())  {
      return $this->redirect('sfGuardAuth/secure');
    }
```

So if you are not admin OR faculty, you get the redirect.

Is this a syntax or logic issue?

**UPDATE**

This is working, but it seems wrong logically

```
if (($request->getParameter('profile_type') == 'foo') && (!$this->getUser()->isAdmin() && !$this->getUser()->isFaculty())) {
            return $this->redirect('sfGuardAuth/secure');
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to answer the question, this is what I got to work:

```
if (($request->getParameter('profile_type') == 'foo') && (!$this->getUser()->isAdmin() && !$this->getUser()->isFaculty())) {
            return $this->redirect('sfGuardAuth/secure');
    }
```

I am not sure how the OR/AND operator is working to get the desired result, but it works, so that is an ok compromise.

Answer (score 1):

```
(!$this->getUser()->isAdmin() || !$this->getUser()->isFaculty())
```

should be

```
!($this->getUser()->isAdmin() || $this->getUser()->isFaculty())
```

Update, with more explanation: you want to redirect the user if both `isAdmin` and `isFaculty` return false, and not redirect if either is yes.

If both are false:

`!(false || false)` == `!false` == `true` => redirect
`!(true || false)` == `!true` == `false` => no redirect

Comment: Isn't that if user is NOT admin or IS Faculty? It should be user is NOT admin or NOT faculty. I gave it a spin, and it worked for admin and not for faculty. See edited post to see what is working, although it does not make sense to me.